# Return select statement without phone area code

Tags: sql, select, format

I'm stuck and I can't seem to think how you would do this, but for example, how would format my phone number with out the first 3 digits.

```
SELECT VendorContactFName + ' ' + SUBSTRING(VendorContactLName, 1, 1) + '.' 
          AS [Contact], VendorPhone AS Phone
FROM Vendors
```

Comment: Always tag the correct DBMS to get fast response. SQL is not DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip the first 3 digits of a string with:

```
right(VendorPhone, len(VendorPhone) - 3)
```

(Assuming from `AS [Contact]` and `SUBSTRING` that you're using SQL Server.)

Comment: Thanks, here is how i did it
`RIGHT(VendorPhone, 8) `